# I would like to label the points with values in polar plot in Matlab

Tags: matlab, polar-coordinates

Example:
I have

> radians = [0:2pi];

and radius

> values = [-200 -180 -160.....-100]; 
> polarplot(radians,values)

So i have values after each 18 degrees. I want to label the plotted points with values instead of one value on different radius circles.

**Sample illustration:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [this link](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/add-text-to-specific-points-on-graph.html). You can label the points individually with the function `text()`.

Comment: In that case, don't you have to put values manually. Is it possible to label the points directly during plotting?

Comment: polarplot does not offer this functionality